# c# showing a process form seems to get stuck when performing a long running task

Tags: c#, winforms

I am in the process of creating a POS system using C# and WinForms.

I am using a form with some text and an image to indicate when a long running process is performed, like sales printing and DB update after the sale. But when I do that, only the `AjaxLoader` form is showing and it's not calling the update functions below it.

This is my code.

```cs
public void completeSale()//invoked on Sell button
{
    
    loader = new AjaxLoader();//this is a form
    loader.label1.Text = "Printing...";
    ThreadStart threadStart = new ThreadStart(Execution);
    Thread thread = new Thread(threadStart);
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
}

private void Execution()
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { loader.ShowDialog(this); });
    Application.DoEvents();

    update_sale("Sold");//method not getting called at all

    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { loader.Dispose(); });
}
```

This is my Ajax loader form that I need to display, that is supposed to block my POS form. So upon finishing the printing (doing background task) I need to close the loader.

[image: Ajax loader]

The problem is that the lines

```
Application.DoEvents();
update_sale("Sold");//method not getting called at all
```

is never reached.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is this a WinForms application? .Net Framework or .Net Core? I'm asking because Ajax is usually associated with web apps, but your image looks like it could be WinForms..

Comment: try to investigate why update_sale() is never called. Is your thread stuck in Application.DoEvents? Try using a debugger and breakpoints  inside your Execution thread to follow step by step

Comment: @snus74 execution is not reaching update line

Comment: @CobyC this a .net framework winform

Comment: @MorganDev, yes but my question is where is it stuck?

Comment: invoke methods are called on other threads, so they should not block the execution of Execution() method. What happens in Application.DoEvents()?

Comment: @snus74    Application.DoEvents(); is not even getting called. its only showing AjaxForm

Comment: @snus74 if I use loader.Show() the update is getting called but its not showing as modal

Comment: Ouch, that's not how that's done. Can you use Task/async? Or is it an old framework version?

Comment: @Fildor could u show me how to do it am new to C# no Idea how to use Task/async task

Comment: CobyC's answer should be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.ShowDialog()` on a form is a blocking call, so your code will wait until the form that is shown as dialog is `.Closed()`

I would also recommend using using `async Task` as this makes working with `Threads` much much easier!

I've changed your code to show this.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await completeSale();
    }

    AjaxLoader loader = null;
    public async Task completeSale()//invoked on Sell button
    {
         //for info, this is how I set up AjaxLoader form properties in the designer.
         loader = new AjaxLoader();
         loader.label1.Text = "Printing...";
         loader.TopMost = true;
         loader.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
         loader.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
         loader.ShowInTaskbar = false;
         loader.ControlBox = false;
         loader.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        //loader.PointToClient(this.DesktopLocation);

        await Execution();   
    }

    private async Task Execution()
    {
        
        if (loader.InvokeRequired)
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { loader.Show(this); });
        else
            loader.Show(this);
        //Application.DoEvents();

        await update_sale("Sold");

        if (loader.InvokeRequired)
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { loader.Close(); });
        else
            loader.Close();
        
    }

    private async Task update_sale(string v)
    {
        //long running process like printing etc..
        await Task.Delay(3000);
    }
}
```

this will do something like this:

[image]

On the AjaxLoader form I added a progress bar that is set to `style = Marquee`

Comment: I have done exactly that and its not showing the AjaxLoader

Comment: did you set `AjaxLoader` to `TopMost = true;`? you could also do `loader.Show(this);` can you debug and are all the lines reached?

Comment: now it shows but one more problem. my pos form is maximised(Full screen) now when the loader.close() method is called its making my pos form to get minimized (show above task bar) but when my pos form load it is full screen hiding even task bar

Comment: I have used flat ui design so what is happening is after loader.close() its making the form pos to appear above task bar but i need my form to be always full screen

Comment: that is strange indeed, are you sure your AjaxLoader `WindowState = Normal`. Remove the `loader.PointToClient(this.DesktopLocation);` and change it to `loader.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;` I'll also update the code. although this should not make any difference. When you start your POS screeen is it maximised?

Comment: when i start pos screen its maximised

Comment: when you say 'flat ui design' do you mean without borders or control boxes (the _ [] x) in the top right hand corner? the `loader` should not change anything about the main POS screen. Are you sure you didn't type a `this.` instead of a `loader.` somewhere? I tested my example by setting the main screen to be maximised and it all works as I'd imagine it should. Also if the POS screen is maximised does it still show the control boxes ( _ [] x )?

Comment: I mean without _[]x and control box=false,My pos screen has no _[]x

Comment: I have not used this. instead of loader anywhere

Comment: infact its making the main pos screen to get minimized upon close()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220510/discussion-between-cobyc-and-morgandev).